# Quiero implementar un sistema Multi-Cuenta en Django

Tags: django, django-forms, modelorelacional

quizás sea sencillo de implementar pero con mi poca experiencia no logro dar con el resultado.
Explico a continuación: Quiero crear una aplicación que maneja Centros de Entrenamiento(Cursos), en ese caso según mi lógica y utilizando el sistema de auntenticación de django he creado un  modelo llamado : User que es una extensión del modelo User propiamente y a este modelo le he agregado un campo llamado is_account, con la finalidad de diferenciar cuando es una cuenta o cuando será un usuario normal.

```
class User ( AbstractUser ) :  # Extendind the User django model
    id = ULIDField ( default=default, primary_key=True, editable=False )
    is_account = models.BooleanField ( default=True )
    signup_confirmation = models.BooleanField ( default=False )
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField ( 'email address', unique=True )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

¿Donde radica el problema?
Si un Usuario es tipo account, entonces eso quiere decir que una cuenta puede tener varios centros de Educación.

Ahora bien, un Centro de Educación: tendrá un modulo donde podrá agregar usuarios que deben poder autenticarse dentro de la aplicación:
En resumen: tengo dos relaciones de una a muchos que se cruzan y no se como hacer:
es decir:
Una cuenta tiene muchos centros y Un centro tiene muchos usuarios

También podría ser manejable en el inicio que una cuenta tenga un solo centro , pero si un centro tenga varios usuarios.

Nota: Hay que destacar que los usuarios tipo cuenta solo se crean cuando alguien se da de alta por app, es decir que una cuenta viene a ser como la creación de un centro, ya dentro de la aplicación todos los usuario que cree ese centro serán de tipo BaseUser como lo he llamado.

De antemano Gracias.

Comment: No entendí muy bien el problema... porque no simplemente haces una relación de muchos a muchos entre un "usuario" y un "centro"?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo lo que quieres hacer, lo más sencillo seria la relación muchos a muchos que ya te sugirieron. Otra solución más compleja pero que yo he implementado con éxito es tener una tercera tabla y crear algo como

```
class PerfilAdministrador(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    centros = models.ManyToMany(CentrosEducacion, ...)
    ...otros campos necesarios para el perfil administrador
```

Al crear el nuevo usuario si  is_account == True disparo un signal que crea el PerfilAdministrador